# What is the optimal number of trials in Optuna with TPESampler?

Tags: optimization

Just for context, I am using optuna to optimize hyperparameters of BERT model.

I limited all my hyperparameter values to discrete and there are around 2000 possible combinations.

I was wondering if there are any calculations/guidelines/empirical suggestions on how many trials one should run? I know it is somehow individual, but I was wondering id someone maybe has some experience regarding that.

Will 50 trials suffice for example?